# How do I stop Excel applying styles from previous rows into subsequent rows?

Tags: excel

I have an issue with Excel where when I paste some formatted cells in, some subsequent rows inherit the style from above. This is unwanted behaviour and I can't seem to stop Excel from doing this. Does anyone know how to stop this behaviour?

To explain further, in the image below you can see cells A1-A5 have a formatting of a grey background and bold text. If I copy cells A1-A5 and paste them into a new workbook, if I type into cells A6, A7 or A8 then the style (grey background and bold) is automatically applied. If I type into cell A9 then this style is not applied.

[image]

What is going on?

This only happens when I **paste** into a new workbook. It doesn't happen if I was to apply the style to cells in an open workbook.

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Create a new spreadsheet
2. In cells A1 to A5, put the letters 1 to 5
3. Format cells A1 to A5 and make the background light grey and the font bold.
4. Select Cells A1 to A5 and copy them.
5. Create a new workbook
6. In the new workbook, go to cell A1 and press CTRL-V to paste.
7. Move to cell A9 and type anything. It will be in normal style
8. Move to cell A8 and type anything. It will have the same style as the cells A1-A5

Why is Excel doing this and how can I make it stop doing it?

I am using Excel version 14.0.7153.5000 (32-bit) on Windows 10.

Comment: I can answer the why at least. Excel is trying to be helpful and is figuring that the added value is a part of the same series as the rows above (it does it across columns as well). I know it's been a handy feature for me when I was creating data tables and realized I was missing a column.

Comment: I think the formatting not getting inherited might be the # of rows/columns skipped. As for a possible solution, I did some poking around and if you manually apply a format to a cell it should break the continuity, so Excel doesn't apply from there on. Can't say that's fool-proof though. Any reason you can't finish adding the necessary data and then remove the fill? Once you do that, values added in the future shouldn't inherit.

Answer (score -2):

Copy cells without any styles applied, then continue. Anytime you copy/paste it, it will assume you want to keep the style applied.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.